# countForFetchRequest and executeFetchRequest return different numbers of results

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I'm finding that a NSFetchRequest is returning different results for a count and for an execute.

I have a Product entity and a Size entity. A Product has many Sizes.

I have two products, productA and productB. ProductA is only available in size1 and productB is available in both size1 and size2.

Given the NSPredicate

'`ANY sizes.#size IN {"size1", "size2"}`'

I'm finding that it returns 3 for the `countForfetchRequest` but an array of 2 items when I execute the fetch request.

The count is the value that is incorrect. ProductB has both sizes and seems to be being counted twice in the `countForfetchRequest` but obviously only returned once by the `executeFetchRequest` call.

I've tried setting `setReturnsDistinctResults:YES` with no effect.

Comment: Is it possible you have a dirty managed object context when you make the count call? i.e. there is a temporary object in the context that could be throwing off the count, or are these two calls made back to back?

Comment: Made back to back, on the same managed context. And the bug is completely repeatable so the context isn't being used by any other thread by mistake etc. I like the thinking though; I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: That's interesting the only thing I can think it's doing is matching each object n times for the n values in the array.  Thus you have 2 objects but 3 actual #sizes that match.  I think this would be easy enough to validate by changing your sizes relationship to a single entity, and checking the count result.

Comment: Yea, if I count where all results just have a 1->1 relationship, it returns the correct amount. I'm interested in why the count and execute for the same predicate were different and how to configure the request so they are the same :(

Comment: Looks to me like countForFetchRequest and executeFetchRequest have different implementations. The latter uses the expensive fetching that actually instantiates and returns objects. The first one just iterates through the database and finds all matches. I think this is a conflict of interests here: either a quick or a correct count method. One that needs to simply count and one that needs to track all objects and exclude duplicates from the counting...

Comment: Will you please explain exactly what kind of query are you issuing? It is not clear (to me) from your description ("A Product has many Sizes") if every product has at least one size. If this is the case, then your predicate is useless because then you could just fetch every product without a predicate. Otherwise, if a product may have zero sizes, then your predicate is wrong and you need to modify it.

Comment: Hi Max - you're right but I thought that setting the request to not allow duplicates would fix that (at the cost of a slightly slower count) :(

Comment: Hi unforgiven - in my example problem product A has one size and product B has two - in my data set every product has at least one size.

Comment: If every product has at least one size, then the predicate is useless. You can simply fetch directly the objects belonging to the Product entity.As I told you, a very different case would be if some of your products may have zero sizes.

Comment: You're missing the point of my problem - in my real app I need the predicate because it does rule out some products that I don't want to count. The question just contains the simplest set of data that exhibits my problem so yea, in this case, the predicate is useless but even with the predicate, it should return the same count for countWith and executeRequest method calls which is the problem I need to solve :)

Comment: Yes, I am probably missing the point. That was the reason for asking what kind of query are you trying to issue. In your case, what products you need to rule out? Those having exactly a specified number of sizes, say 2? I need to fully understand this in order to help you. And, yes, the counts must agree, but this will happen only if you use a correct predicate.

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of products that have sizeA OR sizeB (or both) - products that don't have sizeA or sizeB should be excluded from the result set. Executing the predicate works perfectly, the count with the same predicate doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified the predicate in the answer. Note that the same considerations regarding the parsing problems you may encounter (given in one of my previous comment) still apply. I am assuming that you have multiple sizes, say sizeA, sizeB, sizeC etc. You need a subquery to deal correctly with your to-many relationship in Core Data, as shown in the following predicate

EDIT:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(sizes.@count == 1 || sizes.@count == 2) && (1 == SUBQUERY(sizes, $sub, $sub.#size == %@ || $sub.#size == %@).@count  || 2 == SUBQUERY(sizes, $sub, $sub.#size == %@ || $sub.#size == %@).@count)", yourSizeAvariable, yourSizeBvariable];
```

Let me know if this works correctly for you.

Comment: I have two problems - firstly, I constantly get the error __Unable to parse the format string__ regardless of what I try. Secondly I don't see how this will help my query - this subquery will return a collection of sizes - how to I then test my product against this collection - I really wish that the exception was a little forthcoming to help me debug some more :(

Comment: The query, when run against the Product entity, should return all of the products having sizeA or sizeB (or both). The parsing problem may be related to the use of # to escape the "size" keyword which is reserved in Core Data. Try without the #, but I guess it will not work. If possible, try to change the "size" attribute to something different, say "dimension" and then change the predicate accordingly, removing the #.

Comment: About your concern "I don't see how this will help my query - this subquery will return a collection of sizes - how to I then test my product against this collection": this is not correct. Remember that you run the query against the Product entity, therefore, you always get back products, not sizes: you get back the products whose collection of sizes is exactly the one you specify. However, to simplify this, the new predicate now checks for counts, returning products matching the counts.

Comment: Hi, I worked it out on the walk home - it was late and I was being an idiot! The format needed the .@count on the end - I was just getting the subquery and then not testing it against anything! It works 100% now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think when you do a count, it is counting the number of rows returned from the sql query. As you are querying the size table, you get back 3 because the equivalent sql would return 3 rows.

When you do a fetch, you get 2 because you will only get back two product objects. However if you looked inside those products to the number of size objects, you will find 3.

Oh, and the select distinct will not work because you have 3 unique sets of values :-)

Comment: Yea, you're absolutely right - turns out I need a subquery to remove that :( I just assumed (incorrectly) that they would return the same number - @unforgiven pointed me on the right track :) Thanks.